# Adding to a wait queue

Tags: linux-kernel

I was wondering how I add a `task_struct` to a Wait Queue in a linux kernel module? For example if I want to add a `task_struct` called task to a `WaitQueue`, what function could I use to achive this?

I understand how to add the current module to a wait queue but I want to add other running processes to a queue, for example if vi was running, I need to add that to a wait queue.

Comment: You should clarify the question, I don't understand what 'item' is. Mention what APIs you are trying to use and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: basically I need to know how to add a task_struct to a wait queue

Answer (score 3):

You can make the current task block on an waitqueue with `wait_event*()` functions. See [this tutorial](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-6-sect-2), section '6.2.2. Simple Sleeping'.

Comment: ok, so I have a wait queue called wait defined in my module. If I call something like: `wait_event_timeout(wait, somecondition, 30*HZ)` (I need the process to wake after 30 seconds has passed). How does this know what specific task I want to add to the Wait Queue called wait?

Comment: It only blocks the tasks that call `wait_event*()`, i.e. the `current` task, meaning that if you want a task to sleep on that wait queue, you have to get a hold of its execution context. The most standard way is to implement a `/proc` or `/sys` file and have your program open/read/write it.